# How to document Rspec's let type

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine, yard

Lets say I have following code

```rb
let(:document) { FactoryBot.create :document }
let(:mail) do
  # @type [User]
  celebrated_user = FactoryBot.create :user
  # @type [Rule]
  rule = FactoryBot.create :rule, document: document
  CelebrationMailer.birthday celebrated_user, document, rule
end
```

CelebrationMailer#birthday is documented as follows

```rb
# @param [User] celebrated_user
# @param [Document] document
# @param [Rule] rule
```

In the `let(:mail)` RubyMine (and probably some other tools with types) recognize *document* variable as type Object.

[image: RubyMine's tooltip about wrong type]

How can I document the *let*, so tools recognize *document* let/variable as Document type?

I've tried `@type`, `@return`, `@attr_reader`.

Comment: In case that might be done with `macro` expansion as in the answer below then at the moment it's not supported in RubyMine, please add your vote to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20130

Answer (score 1):

Well, what does `let` do? It creates a method whose name is given by the symbol argument and whose return value is given by the return value of the block.

So, if you wanted to write a type for that, you would have to

- take the symbol and turn it into a method name
- take the return type of the block and turn it into the return type of the method

I am pretty sure that is not possible with RDoc or YARD type notation.

So, the best thing you can do is a [synthetic attribute reader](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#attribute):

```rb
# @!attribute [r] document
#   @return [Document] a fake document
let(:document) { FactoryBot.create :document }
```

Note that YARD *does* support [macros](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#macro), but macros obviously only have access to what is in the source code, and the return type of the block is *not* part of the source code. In fact, the documentation block you showed looks like it was generated by a macro that looks somewhat like this:

```rb
# Defines a memoized method
# @param [Symbol] name the method name
# @param block how to compute the value
# @!macro [attach] let
#   @!attribute [r] $1
#     @return the value defined by the block
def let(name, &block) end
```

This will tell YARD that wherever it sees a call to `let`, it should insert a synthetic documentation block for an attribute reader whose name is the first argument to `let`.

However, it will not allow you to use the type of the block. These are the only interpolation variables that exist:

- `$0` - the method name being called
- `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, … - the Nth argument in the method call
- `$&` - the full source line

What *would* work, is if `let` took a second argument that is the type, then you could write a macro like this:

```rb
# Defines a memoized method
# @param [Symbol] name the method name
# @param [Module] type the type of the memoized value
# @param block how to compute the value
# @!macro [attach] let
#   @!attribute [r] $1
#     @return [${-1}] the value defined by the block
def let(name, type, &block) end
```

And then you would call it like this:

```rb
let(:document, Document) { FactoryBot.create :document }
```

But, that is not how RSpec is designed, so the best you can do is the synthetic attribute reader from my first suggestion.